# Interface Builder: How To Set Only The Height As An Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

When trying to set the constraints of a UIView in the interface builder. When I control drag it gives me the option to set a static height, width, or aspect ratio.

[image]

However adding this adds constraints to the width and height.

[image]

However I only want the height to be based on an aspect ratio (while the width is equal to the superview width). Can you suggest how I can set a height only aspect ratio constraint?

Answer (score 1):

1. Leave width and height constrained by aspect ratio.
2. Select your view and click the "Pin" button at the lower right of the canvas (it looks like a square TIE fighter). In the "Spacing to nearest neighbor" section, add constraints for leading and trailing space to the superview. Set them to -16 if "Constrain to margins" is checked. Otherwise, use zero. These constraints are what will make your view as wide as the superview.
3. You'll also need to set a constraint that defines the Y position of the view (top space to superview, vertical center in superview, whatever makes sense for your layout).

[image]